# mapStateToProps not called at the first call to the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I convert observable-react-project to Redux. I have main container - App.js and his include next methods:

```
handleDone () {
    this.setState({ showPLock: false });
}

render () {
    return (
        <div className="mainContainer">
            {this.props.children}
            {
                this.state.showPLock
                    ? <PCode handleDone={this.handleDone.bind(this)}/>
                    : null
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

In the first start app showPLock: true.
Code PCode:

```
class PCode extends Component{
constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        passcode: ''
    };
}

render () {
    //something doing
}
}

PCode.contextTypes = {
   router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

PCode.propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(stateStore) {
    const { authReducer } = stateStore;
    if (authReducer.pcode !== null) {
        //something return
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PCode);
```

A problem in call mapStateToProps. He is not called immediately at hit on a the component. Consequently, if I call in render something, for example:

```
const { data } = this.props;
```

of course, will issue an undefined.

Why mapStateToProps not called at the first call to the component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `mapStateToProps` should execute on first mount of the component.

Two things to check:

- Are you sure the function isn't being called? Make sure you return an object from `mapStateToProps`, even if it is just an empty `{}`
- The `PCode` class should probably be extending `React.Component`: `class PCode extends React.Component {}`

Comment: 1) function in PCode mapStateCalled called, after call mapStateCalled App.js 2) checked, all right

Comment: So what is the current problem? Please update your code to show where you are at now.

Comment: All the same problem. 1 check not correct because I marked in debug this function. 2 check - ok, but I'm already extends own BaseComponent and him extends React.Component. Ease I update 'code to show' extends React.Component

Comment: Can you try extending ``React.Component`` instead of ``BaseComponent``, that will indicate whether ``BaseComponent`` is interfering. Also posting the skeleton of the ``BaseComponent`` might help.

Answer (score -2):

I'm trying. I said that to simplify this question, I extend  React.Component... Not this check problem!